# Python update, broke yum and python

Tags: python, centos, yum

Ok, I've really ballsed up a server and wondering if the easiest way from this point is to reinstall the OS and restore the files. (We have file backups, but not bootable server backups)

I stupidly followed this tutorial, without reading the whole thing: http://wiki.railsmachine.com/RpmforgeRepository

And the fix posted at the bottom didn't work. I tried to uninstall and reinstall python from source, and that appears to have made things worse. at the minute, the main errors I'm seeing are:

```
[root@ tmp]# yum instal asjkdhaskdh
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

And when I tried to install from source, I was told I have no C compiler. Is there another way of reinstalling Python that I should try? I'm on CentOS.

Any help *greatly* appreciated!
Thanks guys.

Comment: This should be on serverfault, not stackexchange.

Comment: I've flagged it for transfer to Server Fault.

Comment: The easiest would probably be to boot from a bootable media, wipe OS partition and reinstall. (You do have `/` and `/home` on different partitions, right?)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install python using rpm? Just download RPM file from distribution for your architecture and issue something like

```
rpm -Uvh python-2.6.6-29.el6.i686.rpm
```